# Kubernetes Ingress Route One Host

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

In my Azure AKS cluster I was defined namespace dev with some services.My idea is connect to them from React static app under SSL.For this reason I maded Ingress controller with certificate manager. The controller was work properly but with one unexpected bug.I use my own domain with DNS Zone and records.The idea is when I go to qa.mysite.com , ingress must go to payment-svc "/api/health" and if /web go to web-svc "/".The problem is that when I use path Prefix with "/" the controller does not route to any related service.The route only happens when I use deafult prefix "/".The error is Not Found for Nginx or browser not found

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-portals
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - qa.mysite.com # update IP address here
      secretName: app-web-cert
  rules:
  - host: qa.mysite.com # update IP address here
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /web  # I tried with a lot of services and prefixes but same result
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webapp1-svc # After I tried with the same service payment-servive but not work on qa.mysite.com/web/api/health
            port: 
              number: 80
      - path: /  # The route works only here qa.mysite.com/api/health
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: payment-service
            port: 
              number: 80
```

- qa.mysite.com/api/healt works in this service I have endpoint /api/health
- qa.mysite.com/web or anything else /health  qa.mysite.com/web/api/health .... did not

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but ingress-configuration, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @HarshManvar qa.mysite.com/web or anything else /health qa.mysite.com/web/api/health .... did not

Comment: just like `payment-service`  service has `/api/health` endpoint, does the `webapp1-svc` service have `/web/api/health` endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path` specified in the ingress is passed to the service in its entirety. So, your `webapp1-svc` should support endpoints starting `/web`. However, most likely you do not.

So, alternative is to rewrite the url when sending requests to `webapp1-svc`.
Thus you have one ingress definition which sends requests to `payment-service` (and does not rewrite URLs).

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-portals-payments
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - qa.mysite.com
      secretName: app-web-cert
  rules:
  - host: qa.mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /  
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: payment-service
            port: 
              number: 80
```

And a second one which rewrites URLs to `webapp1-svc`. It will remove the preceding `/web` when sending requests to `webapp1-svc`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-portals-web
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - qa.mysite.com 
      secretName: app-web-cert
  rules:
  - host: qa.mysite.com 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /web(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webapp1-svc 
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using the 'default-backend'

(https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-backend) , this way you can remove the '/' path and only keep the /web all the other request including the default fqdn will hit the default back-end service. something like below, provided that you have both of services on the same namespace

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-portals
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - qa.mysite.com
      secretName: app-web-cert
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: payment-service
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
    - host: qa.mysite.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /web
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: webapp1-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: No the result are the same

Comment: No the result are the same. The point is that I want route to a multiple services from record "qa" + DNS zone mysite.com. Something like qa.mysite.com/web to web-svc , qa.mysite.com/web1 to web1-svc, qa.mysite.com/web2 to web2-svc.Or may be I need to create separate record in my DNS zone like web.qa.mysite.com, web1.qa.mysite.com but if I have 10 services and 3 other environments stg and dev this is 30 records.

Comment: qa.mysite.com/webone --> webapp-one-svc
qa.mysite.com/webtwo --> webapp-two-svc

this is the default behavior of an ingress, given that you have both the webapp-one-svc and webapp-two-svc on the same namespace.
also keep in mind depending on your ingress controller the path prefix will be added to the request for eg 
qa.mysite.com/webone to webapp-one-svc will be  webapp-one-svc/webone

so if your service is listening on the root path, you will have to strip the prefix so the result would be
qa.mysite.com/webone to webapp-one-svc will be webapp-one-svc